# Selenium to simulate click without loading link?

Tags: python, angular, selenium, automation

I'm working on a project trying to autonomously monitor item prices on an Angular website.

Here's what a link to a particular item would look like:

`https://www.<site-name>.com/categories/<sub-category>/products?prodNum=9999999`

Using Selenium (in Python) on a page with product listings, I can get some useful information about the items, but what I really want is the `prodNum` parameter.
The `onClick` attribute for the items `= clickOnItem(item, $index)`.
I do have some information for items including the presumable `item` and `$index` values which are visible within the html, but I'm doubtful there is a way of seeing what is actually happening in `clickOnItem`.

I've tried looking around using dev-tools to find where `clickOnItem` is defined, but I haven't been successful.

Considering that I don't see any way of getting `prodNum` without clicking, I'm wondering, is there's a way I could simulate a click to see where it would redirect to, but without actually loading the link- as this would take way too much time to do for each item?

Note: I want to get the specific `prodNumber`. I want to be able to hit the item page directly without first going though the main listing page.

Comment: there's ways to use selenium multi-tabs and multi-browsers in selenium. You could direct the new link to that direction, but not sure if it would work with what you're describing.  Can you share the link to your site? -  A second pair of eyes looking at the DOM and the JS couldn't hurt